# Unconventional Bootstrap Navigation doesn't collapse dropdown on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation, navbar, anchor

```
<div id='lineage-center-nav'>
    <nav id='navigation-lineage' role='navigation'>
        <div id='navigation-lineage-shadow'></div> 
    <ul class='nav'><!-- .navbar-nav taken out-->   
       <li class='dropdown1'><a><span>Martial Arts History</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='#lineage-introduction'><span>Introduction (back to top)</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#martial-arts-history'><span>Ancient martial arts history</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       </li>
       <li class='dropdown1'><a href="#lineage-1955-present"><span>Tae Kwon Do..U.S.A. (1955-present)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class='dropdown1'><a><span>Systems descended from Gene Perceval:</span></a>
          <ul id='#collapse-me' class='navbar-collapse'>
             <li><a href='#listing-of-systems'><span>Listing of Systems</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Black-Cat-Kenpo'><span>Black Cat Kenpo Karate Federation</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="#American-Combat-Karate"><span>American Combat Karate System</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#American-Tae-Kwon-Do'><span>American Tae Kwon Do Moo Duk Kwan -<br>Federation</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Norwegian-Branch'><span>Norwegian Branch: Tae Kwon Do -<br>Moo Duk Kwan</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Tonji-System'><span>Tonji System</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Hard-Soft-System'><span>Hard/Soft system</span></a></li>   
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul> 
    </nav><!-- END '#navigation-lineage --->
</div><!-- END '#lineage-center-nav' -->
```

The ID: (#collapse-me) is what I can't get to collapse on click. I'm using this for in-page anchor tag linking. I need help with the html structure and the javascript to make the dropdown collapse. You can see this in action here: http://www.grandmastergeneperceval.com/lineage.php

The tan-colored menu at the top of the page will stick to the window as you scroll, and I added ID (#collapse-me) to try a number of different things as well as javascript solutions from stackoverflow, but I can't get any of them to work.
You should also know that I used media queries to pull in a separate mobile navigation for bootstrap. I don't want to add in a toggle for this navigation, I just want the UL to collapse after click.

Supposedly, this code is the solution:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
      $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
  });
</script>
```

This doesn't work for me obviously because I don't know the html structure - - particularly where to put .navbar-collapse.

And, as you can see, I got the MOBILE version of bootstrap navigation to collapse using an onclick event (proposed solution from stackoverflow), rather than using javascript to collapse the menu, but this obviously doesn't work for the above because there's no button toggle (I dont want to use) and it's a hover event, not click:

```
<div id='lineage-nav-xs-container'> 
<nav id='navigation-lineage-xs' class='navbar navbar-inverse' role="navigation"> <!-- .goToTop-xs in javascript, lineage.php, top of page. -->
<div id='navigation-lineage-shadow-xs'></div>
<div class='navbar-header'>
        <span class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lineage shortcut menu:</span>

        <button id='lineage-xs-button' type="button" class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-lineage-collapse"> <!-- Set the data-target equal to the ID name of the div that holds the class of 'navbar-collapse' so that the main navigation menu doesn't collapse as well. #lineage-xs-button only serves for selecting this button so the toggle of main navigation isn't selected. -->
        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>
</div><!-- END '#navbar-header' --->
<div id='navigation-lineage-collapse' class='collapse navbar-collapse'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
       <li class='dropdown'><a href="#" class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle="dropdown">Martial Arts History <b class='caret'></b></a>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#lineage-introduction'><span>Introduction (back to top)</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#martial-arts-history'><span>Ancient martial arts history</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li><!-- 'dropdown' is used by bootstrap main navigation, so 'dropdown1' will be used instead. -->
       <li id='lineage-submenu-480px'><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href="#lineage-1955-present">Tae Kwon Do Moo Duk Kwan U.S.A. - (1955-present)</b></a></li> <!-- mobile small -->
       <li id='lineage-submenu-479px'><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href="#lineage-1955-present">Tae Kwon Do..U.S.A. <br />(1955-present)</b></a></li> <!-- mobile extra small allowing for <br /> -->
       <li class='dropdown xs-fix-menu'><a href="#" class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle="dropdown">Systems descended from Gene Perceval <b class='caret'></b></a>
          <ul id='lineage-submenu-480px' class='dropdown-menu'><!-- Don't forget that this <ul> needs class='dropdown-menu' to make it a dropdown menu for mobile -->
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#listing-of-systems'><span>Listing of Systems</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Black-Cat-Kenpo'><span>Black Cat Kenpo Karate Federation</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href="#American-Combat-Karate"><span>American Combat Karate System</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#American-Tae-Kwon-Do'><span>American Tae Kwon Do Moo Duk Kwan Federation</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Norwegian-Branch'><span>Norwegian Branch of Tae Kwon Do Moo Duk Kwan</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Tonji-System'><span>Tonji System</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Hard-Soft-System'><span>Hard/Soft system</span></a></li>  
          </ul>
          <ul id='lineage-submenu-479px' class='dropdown-menu'>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#listing-of-systems'><span>Listing of Systems</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Black-Cat-Kenpo'><span>Black Cat Kenpo <br />Karate Federation</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href="#American-Combat-Karate"><span>American Combat <br />Karate System</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#American-Tae-Kwon-Do'><span>American Tae Kwon Do - <br />Moo Duk Kwan Federation</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Norwegian-Branch'><span>Norwegian Branch of <br />Tae Kwon Do Moo Duk Kwan</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Tonji-System'><span>Tonji System</span></a></li>
             <li><a onclick = $('#lineage-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click(); href='#Hard-Soft-System'><span>Hard/Soft system</span></a></li>  
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- END '#navigation-lineage-collapse' ----> 
</nav><!-- END '#navigation-lienage-xs' ----->
</div>

#navigation-lineage li.dropdown1:hover > ul {
  display: block;  /* Displays dropdown menu on list-item hover. */
  position:absolute;
  top:22px; /* This pulls up the dropdown menu so it meets with the top menu. Change these nunbers, and the menu will collapse. */
  left:-1px; 
  min-width: 100%; 
  text-align:left;
  padding-top:9px;
  padding-bottom:11px; /* This prevents the bottom border-radius from becoming square by hover image. */
  border-radius:0px 7px 7px 7px;
  z-index:+1;
}

/* ADDED HOVER */
#navigation-lineage li.dropdown1:hover > ul li a { /* Effect the text of the dropdown menu items. */
    min-width:270px; /* width of menu selector */
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    padding-left:26px;
    padding-right:4px;
    border-top:0px none;
    text-align:left;
    display: block;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#000000;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    text-shadow:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

This script ALMOST works. Gets the menu to disappear. But I can't get the .dropdown-menu to appear again after 100ms.:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(event) {
      setTimeout(function (){
      $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('hide');
       }, 100);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript's first function is to "clear" any class previously set by clicking on .dropdown-menu li a. When you hover over {.dropdown1 la a} (or .dropdown la a), it applies bootstrap's '.hide' class to the .dropdown-menu.

```
<nav id='navigation-lineage' role='navigation'>
    <div id='navigation-lineage-shadow'></div> 
    <div class='navbar-header'>
        <button id='lineage-xs-button' type="button" class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-me"> 
        </button>
    </div><!-- END '#navbar-header' --->
    <ul class='nav'><!-- no 'navbar-nav' class. -->
       <li class='dropdown1'><a><span>Martial Arts History</span>    </a><!-- see NOTES below. href tag is omitted only for desktop view (no toggle). -->
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
             <li><a href='#lineage-introduction'><span>Introduction (back to top)</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#martial-arts-history'><span>Ancient martial arts history</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       </li>
       <li class='dropdown1'><a href="#lineage-1955-present"><span>Tae Kwon Do..U.S.A. (1955-present)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class='dropdown1 navbar-collapse'><a><span>Systems descended from Gene Perceval:</span></a><!-- see NOTES below. href tag is omitted only for desktop view (no toggle). -->
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
             <li><a href='#listing-of-systems'><span>Listing of Systems</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Black-Cat-Kenpo'><span>Black Cat Kenpo Karate Federation</span></a></li><!-- Target: #systems-collapse --><!-- Black-Cat-Kenpo -->
             <li><a href="#American-Combat-Karate"><span>American Combat Karate System</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#American-Tae-Kwon-Do'><span>American Tae Kwon Do Moo Duk Kwan -<br>Federation</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Norwegian-Branch'><span>Norwegian Branch: Tae Kwon Do -<br>Moo Duk Kwan</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Tonji-System'><span>Tonji System</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#Hard-Soft-System'><span>Hard/Soft system</span></a></li>   
          </ul>
            <script>
                  $(document).ready(function () {
                      $(".dropdown1").hover(function(event) { //hover on main menu item..
                          $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('hide'); //clear previous 'hide' class applied to dropdown-menu.
                      });
                      $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(event) {                            
                          $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('hide'); //On click, apply bootstrap's class 'hide'.       
                      });     
                  });
            </script>
       </li>
    </ul> 
</nav><!-- END '#navigation-lineage --->
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript, with the onclick function in HTML code in menu items:

```
enter cod<div id='etiquette-center-nav'><!-- .goToTop-lg in javascript: --><!-- Sticky window script resides in <head> of etiquette.php page. ID's are referenced in there! -->
<nav id='navigation-etiquette'><!-- role='navigation' can be omitted here. It is only required for the mobile view because of conflict with the main page navigation when cookies are turned on with minification of php files. -->
    <div id='navigation-etiquette-shadow'></div>
    <ul class='nav' itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><!-- no 'navbar-nav' class. -->            

       <li id='etiquette-main-buttons' class='dropdown1'><a><span>Etiquette General Concepts</span></a><!--id='etiquette-main-buttons' used in script below to hide menu. See line 48 in index.css  -->
          <ul id='etiquette-dropdown-menu' class='dropdown-menu'>
             <li itemprop="name"><a onclick="toggleHide()" itemprop="url" href='#header-container'><span>Introduction (back to top)</span></a></li><!-- #header-container is inside file: includes/header-start.php -->
             <li itemprop="name"><a onclick="toggleHide()" itemprop="url" href='#general-concepts'><span>General Concepts</span></a></li><!-- Target: #systems-collapse --><!-- Black-Cat-Kenpo -->e here
```

Then put this script immediately after the close  tag for the dropdown-menu:

```
            <script>
                function toggleHide() {
                    var element = document.getElementById("etiquette-dropdown-menu");
                        element.classList.add("hidden", "hide");
                        element.onmouseleave = function(){
                            element.classList.remove("hidden", "hide");
                        }
                    }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap MOBILE navigation....This works only if jquery library is added, and the script (below) must go immediately after the UL tag:

```
<div class='navbar-header'>

        <button id='etiquette-xs-button' type="button" class='navbar-toggle margin-left-10px' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-etiquette-collapse"> <!-- Set the data-target equal to the ID name of the div that holds the class of 'navbar-collapse' so that the main navigation menu doesn't collapse as well. #etiquette-xs-button only serves for selecting this button so the toggle of main navigation isn't selected. -->
        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-brand">Etiquette shortcut menu:</div>

</div><!-- END '#navbar-header' -->
<div id='navigation-etiquette-collapse' class='collapse navbar-collapse'><!-- ID "navigation-etiquette-collapse' is referenced only for data-target for <button data-toggle="collapse" -->
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav' itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">

       <li class='dropdown xs-fix-menu'><a href="#" class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle="dropdown">Etiquette Concepts: (First half) <b class='caret'></b></a>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'><!-- Don't forget that this <ul> needs class='dropdown-menu' to make it a dropdown menu for mobile -->
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#header-container"><span>Introduction (back to top)</span></a></li><!-- #header-container is inside file: includes/header-start.php -->
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#general-concepts"><span>General Concepts</span></a></li><!-- Target: #systems-collapse --><!-- Black-Cat-Kenpo -->
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#becoming-a-student"><span>Becoming a Student</span></a></li>
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#outside-the-martialarts-school"><span>Outside the martial arts school</span></a></li>
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#etiquette-and-safety"><span></span>Etiquette when entering school</a></li>
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#etiquette-in-the-reception-area"><span>Etiquette in reception area</span></a></li>
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#uniform-and-belt"><span>Uniform and Belt</span></a></li>
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#advice-from-the-master"><span>Advice from the Master</span></a></li>
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#before-the-class-starts"><span>Before the class starts</span></a></li>
             <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#during-class"><span>During class & requirements</span></a></li>               
          </ul>
```

And the script is:

```
            <script>    
                  $(document).ready(function () {
                  $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(event) {
                          $('#etiquette-xs-button.navbar-toggle').click();        
                      });     
                  });
            </script> -->
```